# Calling intents by http urls in android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, webview, youtube

I have currently a webview in android.
But the webview is unable to show certain urls that contain youtube/flash videos, mp3's, mp4's, 3gp's and so on....

Is it possible to check if an internal application is able to play those formats.
I.E. if the url forwards to a youtube video then it launches the youtube app (if available), or if the url forwards to an mp3 video then it forwards to the music player.

The url that will be processed is send from an external json, so it is variabel.

Furthermore if the url is just a simple webpage (no application except the webbrowser can process it) then it should be shown in the webview.

I have browsed arround and I came up with this start:

```
String url = "url here for example youtube.com/watch?v=.....";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

I was not able to test this part above, but the thing missing in this snipet is, that if the url is just a simple webpage, then I dont want the webbrowser to start, but I just want it to be shown in my simple webview.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I think i've found the answer: 

The android packagemanager has the method: [queryIntentActivities](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html)

This method returns the possible Activities that can listen to the url given to the Action_VIEW of the intent. If the method only returns a webbrowser, then it will show the activity in the webview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set [WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) to your web view, and ovveride `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method.
If URL ends with .mp3 (your specific format) then start intent or override `onReceivedError` method and process error.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I would like to fire an intent with all possible urls, I could do allot of if statements (which is how it is now) since there are many url types, but I am working on a open source application so if there is a cleaner solution, then it would be better :)